# how can i communicate ios side with server side (heroku)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe Payments in my iOS app and i obviously cant store credit card information over the iOS app so i have to create tokens and send that to the server to be charged etc.

My question is how can i communicate iOS => server and vice versa 
My web app is in Rails by the way. 
I read in some places that i might need to create a API on my server? then call it from my iOS side?

if anyone has an idea on how to do such a thing please let me know, i would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must create (or update) your Rails application to expose an HTTP API, which usually communicates using JSON. Your API will need to respond to POST/GET/whatever requests the iOS app make and behave correctly based on what you expect to do (do something with some tokens from my understanding).

Please notice though that handling payments and not having already the knowledge on how to do such a thing might be dangerous for the end user.

To give you a general overview of the process:

- Create Rails routes, controllers, models required to manage the logic of *perform a payment from a token*, this is entirely your job unless the Rails app you are working with, already support this
- Update your iOS app to send, probably with a POST request, the token you talked about, you'll probably need to define some sort of authentication protocol, look into JWT or something similar, you won't have cookies at your disposal in the iOS app

It's a long but interesting task

Comment: could you elaborate on your last sentence.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about you, but when you talk about payments it means you are dealing with customers money. You want to have a very solid ground when dealing with money, a wrong payment or an easily stolen credit card can create a lot of legal issues which you might not like dealing with. That's a very personal opinion, though, but I wanted to point out that while interesting, it has downsides working on it

Comment: ahh i see what you mean, yes thats understandable. I appreciate you thoughts and insight.

Comment: i talked on IRC with some ppl about it and one said `make an endpoint on your server that accepts the token (you probably want info on the item they're ordering and the account they're paying) and charges it. Then configure your app to send that info. To do it properly it gets a bit more complicated, since your server should have access to your database`

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what I described when I said _write the payment logic on server side app_, the way they suggested is definitely the easiest

Comment: so basically ill have to be able to make REST/HTTP request from the iOS side, and have the logic on a server.

Comment: Exactly, you need to implement the logic on the server side to keep code safe